# Prevent Data Loss during PostgreSQL Host Shutdown

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2012

So I've spent the better part of my day (and several searches before) looking for a workable solution to prevent data loss when the host of a PostgreSQL server installation gets rebooted or shut down. We maintain a number of Azure and on-prem servers and the number of times someone has inadvertently shut down the server without first ensuring Postgres is no longer flushing data to disk is far more frequent than it should be. Of note we are a Windows Server shop.

Our current best practice (which if followed appropriately works) is to stop the Postgres service, then watch disk writes to the Postgres data directory in Resource Monitor. Once nothing is writing to that directory, shut down the host. I have to think that there's a better way to ensure that it doesn't get shutdown in a manner that leads to data corruption, regardless of adherence to the best practice (or in some cases, because Windows Update mandates a reboot, regardless of configured settings telling it not to reboot).

Some things I've considered, but have been unable to find solid answers for:

1. Create a scheduled task that uses the "On an event" trigger to monitor the System log for event 1074. It would have to be configured to "run whether the user is logged in or not". The script would cancel the shutdown command with `shutdown /a`, then run a script to elegantly shutdown Postgres. I've seen mixed results on if the scheduled job would reliably trigger before Task Scheduler is terminated in the shutdown sequence.
2. Create a shutdown script using Group Policy. My question there is will it wait for the script to complete before executing the shutdown?

How do you deal with data loss in your Postgres server Windows hosts?

Comment: 1) 'Of note we are a Windows Server shop.'  I'm so sorry e.g. 'because Windows Update mandates a reboot, regardless of configured settings telling it not to reboot' 2) Make sure [fsync](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html) is `on`. Because Postgres should write to WAL first and the worse that happens is it goes into a recovery on restart.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you register PostgreSQL as a Windows service, a shutdown of the machine will automatically shut down PostgreSQL first.

But even without that, a properly configured PostgreSQL server on proper hardware will never suffer data loss (unless you hit a rare PostgreSQL software bug). It is one of the basic requirements for a relational database to survive crashes without data loss.

To enumerate a few things that come to mind:

- make sure that the PostgreSQL parameters `fsync` and `synchronous_commit` are set to `on`
- make sure that you are using a reliable file system for the data files and the WAL (a Windows network share is *not* a reliable file system)
- make sure you are using storage that has no caches that are not battery-backed